# Обьясните код подсчета количества символов строки

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

В чужом проекте я наткнулся на следующий код

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
{
    size_t SizeSTR(const T(&)[])
    {
        return N;
    }

}
```

Данный код считает длинну строки. Но я не совсем понимаю как?

Answer (score 3):

Вы несколько неверно записали функцию. Вот так правильнее:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t SizeSTR(const T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

И это не длина строки, а размер переданного массива. Когда вы передаете в `SizeSTR` массив, то компилятор сразу видит тип и размер этого массива, и инстанцирует шаблонную функцию для соответствующего типа и размера. Ну, и которая, соответственно, возвращает вычисленный компилятором размер.

Например,

```
int a[8];
SizeSTR(a);
```

Компилятор понимает, что `T` - это `int`, а `N` - это 8. Так что ваша функция возвращает 8.

Точно так же при передаче строкового литерала

```
SizeSTR("Hello");
```

компилятор выводит `T` — `const char`, а `N` — 6.